# Order by in SQL query

Tags: sql, tab-ordering

[image: So here are my two tables]

I need to select distinct vehicle.model rows and sort them by the rate.day value.
Little help with a query please?

Thanks for considering my question.

Comment: If you have multiple rows in RATE per vehicle, which row do you want to pick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select distinct model, day_rate from vehicle
  inner join rate on vehicle.vehicle_type = rate.vehicle_type
  order by day_rate
```

Now. Go deliver your homework...

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct v.model
from vehicle v
inner join rate r
on v.vehicle_type = r.vehicle_type
order by r.day_rate
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    v.model
FROM 
    vehicle v
  JOIN
    rate r
      ON r.vehicle_type = v.vehicle_type
ORDER BY r.day_rate
```

or better:

```
SELECT  
    model
FROM 
    vehicle v
GROUP BY 
    model
ORDER BY 
    ( SELECT 
          r.day_rate
      FROM 
          rate r
      WHERE 
          r.vehicle_type = MIN(v.vehicle_type) 
    )
```